# Connecting to aws iot core with mqtt username and password

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, mqtt, aws-iot, aws-iot-core

The example in the aws tutorial does not show the login method via mqtt with username and password. How can I connect with Custom Authentication using username and password?

I tried with custom authentication but it didn't work.

- I tried to create custom authontication with port 443 without using X.509 certificate. link: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/protocols.html

[image: aws iot core document]

- I followed the steps in the aws docs. I edited some parts for login with MQTT username and password.
  link : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/config-custom-auth.html
  [image]
- And this is my Authorizer
  [image]
- This is my Lambda Function (arn addresses are correct)

  ```js
  // A simple Lambda function for an authorizer.

  exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) { 
     var uname = event.protocolData.mqtt.username;
      var pwd = event.protocolData.mqtt.password;
      var buff = new Buffer(pwd, 'base64');
      var passwd = buff.toString('ascii');
      switch (passwd) { 
          case 'test': 
              callback(null, generateAuthResponse(passwd, 'Allow')); 
          default: 
              callback(null, generateAuthResponse(passwd, 'Deny'));  
      }
  };

  // Helper function to generate the authorization response.
  var generateAuthResponse = function(token, effect) { 
      var authResponse = {}; 
      authResponse.isAuthenticated = true; 
      authResponse.principalId = 'TEST123'; 
      
      var policyDocument = {}; 
      policyDocument.Version = '2012-10-17'; 
      policyDocument.Statement = []; 
      var publishStatement = {}; 
      var connectStatement = {};
      connectStatement.Action = ["iot:Connect"];
      connectStatement.Effect = effect;
      connectStatement.Resource = ["arn:aws:iot:eu-west-1:<myarn>:client/myClientName"];
      publishStatement.Action = ["iot:Publish"]; 
      publishStatement.Effect = effect; 
      publishStatement.Resource = ["arn:aws:iot:eu-west-1:<myarn>:topic/telemetry/myClientName"]; 
      policyDocument.Statement[0] = connectStatement;
      policyDocument.Statement[1] = publishStatement; 
      authResponse.policyDocuments = [policyDocument]; 
      authResponse.disconnectAfterInSeconds = 3600; 
      authResponse.refreshAfterInSeconds = 300;
      
      return authResponse; 
  }
  ```
- Everything seems fine when I test it using the aws cli.
  [image]
- I am using node-red for testing. But I can't connect.
  [image]
- I also can't connect when I try with mosquitto.
  [image]

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74702948/edit) the question to provide a link to the docs you mentioned and to show what you've tried and how it failed.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I've made the necessary edits. @hardillb

Answer (score 0):

AWS IoT Core really wants you to use a client certificate to connect to the MQTT broker.

Alternately you can have your server generate a [signature version 4 url](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/protocols.html#mqtt-ws) using your access key id and secret access key for an authorized user. I don't like this way, but it works in a pinch. See https://glitch.com/edit/#!/itp-arduino-workshop?path=AWS-IoT-ws-url.js for one way to do this.

A better way is to setup Cognito to allow access to IoT Core. The [AWS Innovator Island tutorial](https://serverlessland.com/learn/innovator-island) demonstrates how to do this. See the [backend section of part 2](https://www.eventbox.dev/published/lesson/innovator-island/2-realtime/2-backend.html) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I've made the necessary edits. @doncoleman

Answer (score 0):

I made it work [the sample authorizer code](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/config-custom-auth.html) with the following client. No encoding is required for the password.

```
mosquitto_sub \
--cafile AmazonRootCA1.pem \
-h <your-endpoint>-ats.iot.<region>.amazonaws.com \
-p 443 \
-u 'test?x-amz-customauthorizer-name=AuthorizerName' \
-P 'test' \
-t 'notification' \
-i browser \
--tls-alpn mqtt \
-d
Client browser sending CONNECT
Client browser received CONNACK (0)
Client browser sending SUBSCRIBE (Mid: 1, Topic: notification, QoS: 0, Options: 0x00)
Client browser received SUBACK
Subscribed (mid: 1): 0
```

Do you see any error in your logs?

- `aws logs tail --follow AWSIotLogsV2`
- `aws logs tail --follow /aws/lambda/AuthorizerFunctionName`

Comment: The lambda function gives a buffer error, but I removed the decode of the password. lambda function no longer throws an error. But the mosquitto still won't connect. Your username starts with 'test?x-am...' mine is 'user?x-am...' . How do we determine this? (I tried with 'test?x-am..' and it didn't work)

Comment: As the authorizer code does not check username, it can be anything. Do you see any error in IoT Core log? What is your current [log level](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/configure-logging.html#log-level)?

Comment: My log level is "ERROR" and the reason "AUTHORIZATION_FAILURE"

Comment: Seems like you don't have enough permissions from the error message. Try changing the Authorizer function to pass sufficient permissions to your client. How about adding `iot:Receive` and `iot:Subscribe`, for example? Also you may want to change log level to DEBUG.

Comment: I changed the log level to debug, added `iot:Receive` and `iot:Subscribe` permissions, but the same errors occur(AUTHORIZATION_FAILUR). Also I noticed that the console.log I wrote inside the lambda function does not work. Could my lambda function not be triggering at all?

Comment: 1. You can check if your lambda is invoked in the cloudwatch log with the command above.

2. You may want to check `aws iot describe-authorizer --authorizer-name your-authrizer-name`

3. You may want to check policy to invoke lambda. Lambda > Functions > AuthorizerFunction > Configuration tab > Resource-based policy

Comment: I checked the policies and `aws iot describe-authorizer --authorizer-name MyAuthorizer`. policy is correct. lambda function action is `lambda:InvokeFunction`. But `aws logs tail --follow /aws/lambda/myauth` doesn't have any logs.

Comment: I added `console.log(authResponse);` before `return authResponse; `, it prints the object authResponse. There may be something wrong with your lamnda func. How about creating a new one?

"The lambda function gives a buffer error, but I removed the decode of the password. lambda function no longer throws an error." 

It looks that you successfully invoke your lamda. Does it generate logs when you manually run the function?

Comment: I added console.log(authResponse);  before the authResponse return. But it only works when I test it using aws cli. I tried to create a new lambda function, but it still works in aws cli, but it doesn't work when I try it in mosquitto or node-red

Comment: I made Token validation disabled in my case. When I try enabling it, it gets AUTHORIZATION_FAILURE. After that, even when I make disabled, it wasn't reflected properly, and the same error appeared, so maybe it's necessary to recreate Authorizer when you change this setting. If you create a new Authorizer, it needs to match the "AWS:sourceArn" in your lambda resource policy.

Comment: @serkan ersoy. I do have the same setup and the same problem. What works for my, is using not MQTT but WebSocket. Then I see the logs in Cloudwatch. But I do not see the logs for MQTT attemps. It looks like in this case my Lambda is not called either. 

For Testing I use the MQTT Explorer/mqtt cli. My assumption is, that x-amzn-mqtt-ca/ALPN is not set correctly and therefore the MQTT Protocol is not triggered as well.